# Are there cameras that capture not only color but the actual depth?

Tags: camera, computer-vision, photogrammetry

Getting into 3D reconstruction techniques, I'm curious whether there are cameras that capture not only color but the depth at the moment of image being captured. It would appear that getting the depth of a particular pixel on the sensor would be far more accurate than needing to reconstruct after the fact by using many images.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are sensors which are not based on the triangulation principle. They use the time of flight or similar principles to capture the depth for a particular pixel. Take a look at [PMD-Sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-flight_camera#RF-modulated_light_sources_with_phase_detectors)

Answer (score 1):

There are Microsoft Kinect, and Intel® RealSense™ that you can take a look at.